# Extending Ext.data.NodeInterface

Tags: javascript, class, extjs4, prototypal-inheritance

I wanted to add a custom object as treenode in a tree panel.
It will be used as

```
var complex_object = {....}
myTree.getRootNode().appendChild(new MyNode(complex_object));
```

To implement such feature I found `Ext.data.NodeInterface` whcih provides a common interface to tree nodes. So I tried to extend it. Here is how its done.

```
var MYNS = {
       TreeNode: new Ext.Class({
        protocol : "",
        displayName : "",
        extend: 'Ext.data.NodeInterface',
        constructor : function(line) {
            this.protocol = get_protocol(line);
            this.displayName = get_display_name(line);
            var configObj = {
                id : this.protocol + "-" + this.displayName,
                text : this.displayName,
                leaf : true,
                iconCls : protocol+"-user"
            };
            this.callParent([configObj]);
        }
    })
}
```

As it turns out this does not create any extended class of `Ext.data.NodeInterface`.  It however creates object bud has not function from its parent.

```
 var a = new MYNS.TreeNode(...);
 a.appendChild(); // throws error
```

Am I do it wrong? How do Correctly do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Ext.data.NodeInterface` is a 'factory' for decorating the prototype of `Ext.data.Model` classes with properties/functions required.

> This class is used as a set of methods that are applied to the prototype of a Model to decorate it with a Node API. This means that models used in conjunction with a tree will have all of the tree related methods available on the model.

This is how you would use it:

```
Ext.define('app.MyModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    fields: [ /*...*/ ],

    /*...*/
});

Ext.data.NodeInterface.decorate('app.MyModel'); // String will be resolved to Class object internally

var obj = Ext.ModelManager.create(parent, 'app.MyModel');
obj.appendChild(/*...*/);
```

The central method is `Ext.data.NodeInterface#decorate` - see the [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.NodeInterface-static-method-decorate) - which facilitates `#getPrototypeBody` internally. These are both static methods. You could override `getPrototypeBody` to manipulate the class definition.
For other Ext classes to pick up the changes you would rather have to **override** `Ext.data.NodeInterface` instead of **extending** it.

However, another approach is to add the required functionality by **extending `Ext.data.Model`** - this might actually be the more straight-forward approach to your requirement.

Comment: AFAIK `Ext.define` and `new Ext.Class` is same. How does `define` helps here?

Comment: It says what the difference is right in the documentation for Ext.Class: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.Class

Comment: `Ext.define` and `new Ext.Class` are not the same, but I agree that it is not very relevant to the question. After looking into the issue more it seems that the problem is something else. I will update my answer.